# Button alignment is gone when app is displayed Horizontally

Tags: java, android, eclipse, user-interface, android-relativelayout

I have developed an app, which look like below, in vertical view.

[image]

This is the code of this app

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".HomeScreen" >

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:stretchColumns="*"
        android:weightSum="4" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/fBtn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_weight=".3"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="@string/fStr" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/rBtn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_weight=".3"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="@string/rStr" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/sBtn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_weight=".3"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="@string/sStr" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/cBtn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_weight=".3"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="@string/cStr" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/aBtn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_weight=".3"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="@string/aStr" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/lBtn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_weight=".3"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="@string/lStr" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/oBtn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_weight=".3"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="@string/oStr" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/tBtn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_weight=".3"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="@string/tStr" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/eBtn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_weight=".3"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="@string/eStr" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/dBtn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_weight=".3"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="@string/dStr" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/hBtn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_weight=".3"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="@string/hStr" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/aaBtn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_weight=".3"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="@string/aStr" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**strings.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="fStr">Fffffffff</string>
<string name="rStr">Rrrrrr</string>
<string name="sStr">Ssssss       </string>
<string name="lStr">Lllll</string>
<string name="oStr">Oooooooooooo</string>
<string name="tStr">Ttttt</string>
<string name="eStr">Eeeeee</string>
<string name="dStr">Dddddddddd</string>
<string name="cStr">Cccccccc</string>
<string name="hStr">Hhhh</string>
<string name="aStr">Aaaaaaaaaa aaaa</string>

</resources>
```

This app has 2 issues.

1. The gap between button image and text is too much
2. When the app is in horizontal view, the entire alignment is messed up, and get displayed as below.

[image]

As you can see, there is not text!

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: design another layout with the same name for landscape mode res/layout-land/name.xml. http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: create a layout folder with -port name like layout-land-mdpi and define the same layout. In the case of landscape the height will take the wrapcontent val and the width the fill parent. (if that doesnt work, leave it as it is) and test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new folder under res folder named layout-land and put your layout(XML file) in that folder.

See this [doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html)

Comment: folder name is "layout-land" ?

Comment: in your res folder create new folder name it layout-land. And after creating folder put your abc.xml in that folder and make the changes as per your requirement.

Comment: @Artificial_Intelligence yes folder name is layout-land.

Comment: OK, Thanks for the reply. So that means, 2 copies (with some changes) of the same design is going to exist, and android can automatically detect what to load?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. give table row `width` as `match_parent` and `height` as `wrap_content` and remove `weight`. then if you give `weight` for something you need to give `0dp` for particular `height` or `width`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".HomeScreen" >

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:stretchColumns="*"
        android:weightSum="4" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/fBtn"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_weight=".3"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="fStr" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/rBtn"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_weight=".3"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="rStr" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/sBtn"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_weight=".3"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="sStr" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/cBtn"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_weight=".3"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="cStr" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/aBtn"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_weight=".3"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="aStr" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/lBtn"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_weight=".3"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="lStr" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/oBtn"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_weight=".3"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="oStr" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/tBtn"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_weight=".3"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="tStr" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/eBtn"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_weight=".3"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="tStr" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/dBtn"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_weight=".3"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="tStr" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/hBtn"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_weight=".3"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="tStr" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/aaBtn"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_weight=".3"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="tStr" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem is due to the size that image if you take small size images then you face this problem.....if you want put big sized images then You have to change RelativeLayout  to ScrolView 
and then TableLayout height should be wrap_content.....